# gitlab mattermost usage problems

Tags: gitlab, mattermost

I run gitlab and activated mattermost. I created a new project and set up a mattermoast team.

Now I want to add all other users. But my user is no admin in mattermost. how can I solve that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this link](https://docs.mattermost.com/install/config-mattermost-server.html), the first user in the system has the `system_admin` role.

Find the first user that is created on your Mattermost server and use it as an admin account.

Comment: yes that whats I thought ... but the first user has no admin rights

Comment: I run the latest Mattermost using its [Production Docker Deployment](https://docs.mattermost.com/install/prod-docker.html) on my computer. But I have made two changes. First, set the `EnableOpenServer` in the config file to `true`, this will ignore email activation. Second, expose the internal port of the mattermost container for outside. Then, I have used [user creation endpoint](https://api.mattermost.com/#tag/users%2Fpaths%2F~1users%2Fpost) directly to create the first user on the recently run Mattermost.
Using these steps, I have successfully created the first user which was system_admin.